# Vue Application deployement and making changes without project file

Tags: vue.js

A developer created a web front-end and deployed on server. Unfortunately when the vue application was developed I did not receive the original vue files so all I have access to are the files deployed on the server. 
I'm unsure how vue works and if deployment means that the web application is compiled. If this is the case, is it essential to have the original vue project to make changes ? 
What disadvantages will I encounter without the project file?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original developer used VueJS-cli to develop, you should have the source code at `src` folder.

The deployed assets are generated in a build phase, and keep apart from source code.

The deployed code is in folder `dist` in server.

If you only received the `dist` folder (the compiled assets), maybe it is a difficult to reverse engineer the code, because you only have the minified and uglified version of the source code.